# How do I change the display name of a c++ windows service?

Tags: c++, windows-services

Where can I set the display name in the Service Control Manager of a c++ app?

Answer (score 3):

Use [ChangeServiceConfig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681987(v=vs.85).aspx) to change the display name; you can use [ChangeServiceConfig2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681987(v=vs.85).aspx) to change the description.

Comment: looks like only description can be changed via ChangeServiceConfig2

Answer (score 2):

It's in the registry, under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/[yourservicekey]/DisplayName

Comment: you can find out the [yourservicekey] as following: Start->Run->cmd.exe
Type:
sc.exe GetKeyName [display_name_of_service_that_you_want_to_change]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just change the DisplayName of a particular service, it can be done from the command line instead of *risky* registry edits.

```
sc config <ServiceName> DisplayName= <NewName>
```